# Deploying simple Flask application to Azure App Service - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy a simple flask application to an Azure App Service container, however when deploying from github repository I am getting an error saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'`.

I have the requirements.txt file in the project populated using pip freeze > requirements.txt.

requirements.txt

```
bcrypt==4.0.1
cffi==1.15.1
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.6
cryptography==38.0.4
dnspython==2.2.1
Flask==2.2.2
Flask-Cors==3.0.10
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
jwt==1.3.1
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
pathlib==1.0.1
pycparser==2.21
pymongo==4.3.3
six==1.16.0
Werkzeug==2.2.2
Wheelhouse==0.1.4
```

My pipeline yml file:

```
name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - b00782310-com774

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
    SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT: 1

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: '3.8'

      # - name: Create and start virtual environment
      #   run: |
      #     python -m venv venv
      #     source venv/bin/activate
      
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt

      # Optional: Add step to run tests here (PyTest, Django test suites, etc.)

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            . 
            !venv/
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: .

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: 'b00782310-com774'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_AF561207AFB44DF1B5B6F54DFA612E98 }}
```

Any help would be appreciated, tried a lot of tips online but cannot get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried including 'requests' in your requirements:

```
...
pycparser==2.21
pymongo==4.3.3
requests == 2.28.1
six==1.16.0
Werkzeug==2.2.2
...
```

Or add it directly to your yml dependencies, i.e.

```
- name: Install dependencies
  run: |
        pip install -r requirements.txt
        python -m pip install requests
```

This is pretty new to me too - but hopefully this helps.

There's some decent help in app-service [msft github repo too](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/app-service/quickstart-python.md)

Comment: Hi, yea this did work, I only recently used pip freeze requirements.txt before creating this post and didn't realise requests was missing. Was previously pointing to the folder containing the wheels that were required. After manually adding each of the requirements to the requirements.txt file, the deployment went okay. Thanks for your help!